# Baby Rudin Algebraic Completeness of the Complex Field

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

While I am reading Rudin's proof on the completeness of complex field,
[image]
I am stuck in two steps.

The first one is in the derivation of (57). How can $Q(z)$ be represented with $1+b_kz^k+\dots+b_nz_n$ ($1\geq k\geq n$)? I tried to compute some examples but it seems the first $1$ does not appear in the expanded result and the $k$ does not make sense to me.

And the second one is in the derivation of $|1+b_kr^ke^{ik\theta}|=1-r^k|b_k|$. How is this derived? Here's my try:
$$
\begin{align*}
e^{ik\theta}b_k&=-|b_k|\\
b_kr^ke^{ik\theta}&=-r^k|b_k|\\
1+b_kr^ke^{ik\theta}&=1-r^k|b_k|\\
|1+b_kr^ke^{ik\theta}|&=|1-r^k|b_k||\\
\end{align*}
$$
Then use the triangle inequality of complex modulus,
$$
|1-r^k|b_k||\leq1+|-r^k|b_k||=1+r^k|b_k|.
$$
And now I have a result that is different from Rudin's. But suprisingly my way works. With $|1+b_kr^ke^{ik\theta}|=1+r^k|b_k|$,
$$
|Q(re^{i\theta})|\leq1+r^k\{|b_k|+r|b_{k+1}|+\dots+r^{n-k}|b_n|\}.
$$
And with sufficiently small $r$, the expression in the brace is still positive and can be sufficiently small, so is $r^k$, thus $|Q(re^{i\theta})|\leq1+\varepsilon$, and $|Q(re^{i\theta})|\leq1$. The desired contradiction still appears. Is this new argument valid?

---

By the way, here's my attempt computing an example of (57):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $Q(z)=\dfrac{P(z+z_0)}{P(z)}$ and that therefore $Q(0)=\dfrac{P(z_0)}{P(z_0)}=1$. In other words, the constant term of $Q(z)$ is $1$.

Concerning the other doubt, remember that $e^{ik\theta}b_k=-\lvert b_k\rvert$ and that therefore $1+b_kr^ke^{ik\theta}=1-r^k\lvert b_k\rvert$.

Comment: I understand $1+b_kr^ke^{ik\theta}=1-r^k\lvert b_k\rvert$, but in following arguments $|1+b_kr^ke^{ik\theta}|$ is required, and it is equal to $|1-r^k|b_k||$, which is not equal to $1-r^k|b_k|$.

Comment: Since $r^k\lvert b_k\rvert<1$, $1-r^k\lvert b_k\rvert>0$, and therefore$$\lvert1+b_kr^ke^{ik\theta}\rvert=\bigl\lvert1-r^k\lvert b_k\rvert\bigr\rvert=1-r^k\lvert b_k\rvert.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$Q(z)=b_0+b_1z+...+b_nz^n$$
Then
$$1=Q(0)=b_0+0+..+0$$

Thus
$$Q(z)=1+b_1z+...+b_nz^n$$

About $k$: Here Rudin skips the $0$ coefficients. If $b_1 \neq 0$ then $k=1$.

If $b_1=0, b_2 \neq 0$ then $k=2$ and so on. More precisely
$$k= \min \{ j : 1 \leq j \leq n , b_j \neq 0 \}$$